# Utilizo PHP dentro de um HTML ou um HTML dentro de um PHP?

Tags: php, html

Fiz todo meu site em HTML e CSS, só que agora estou precisando utilizar o PHP para enviar alguns dados para um banco de dados. Só que estou com uma dúvida, se modifico todos os meus documentos para .php ou se utilizo o PHP dentro do HTML (se é que é possível).

Comment: Minha opinião? Faça ambos separados e a comunicação entre eles via Ajax.

Comment: Eu recomendo não utilizar php no seu html, faça o PHP trabalhar somente em camada back-end, trazendo tudo por API RestFul..., via javascript. Vai sofrer menos.

Comment: [+] só precisa saber trabalhar com objetos do javascript e interpretação de JSON, que é muito similar ao XML

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Um arquivo HTML com extensão .php vai se comportar **exatamente como HTML**. O interpretador PHP só entra em cena para o que estiver entre `<? ... ?>`.

Neste contexto o ideal é usar tudo .php.

Comment: pelas normas do PHP, sempre utilize <?php ?> ou <?= ?> para impressão

Answer (score 18):

### Respondendo a sua 1ª pergunta

*Preciso alterar todos os meus arquivos apenas para enviar alguns dados para o php e então processá-los e salvar no banco de dados?*

Não! Basta você manter o seu arquivo que contém o formulário por exemplo, e setar a `action` dele para o arquivo `.php`, por exemplo:

`seu_formulario.html`

```
<form action="processa_dados.php" method="post">
    <!-- seus campos e o botão submit aqui -->
</form>
```

Pronto. Com isso você já consegue fazer de maneira simples o que você quer.

`processa_dados.php`

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  // valida e processa os dados
  // redireciona para uma página de sucesso ou erro
}
```

### Respondendo a sua 2ª pergunta

É normal, e não é má prática criar um arquivo por exemplo `index.php`, com todo seu html padrão (`DOCTYPE, html, head, body`, etc) junto ao PHP para mostrar variaveis, utilizar condições (`if, else, foreach, while`). Como no exemplo abaixo (CakePHP):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>
    <?php
      if(isset($titulo)) {
        echo $titulo . ' | ';
      } 
    ?>
    StackOverflow
  </title>
</head>
<body>

  <?php include('cabecalho.php') ?>

  <?php echo $conteudo ?>

  <?php include('rodape.php') ?>

</body>
</html>
```

O que é má prática pelo contrário, é criar uma classe por exemplo, que retorna o HTML da sua página por completo, concatenando já as variáveis, etc.

```
<?php

class Exemplo
{

  public function resposta()
  {
    echo '<div id="answer-7706" class="answer" data-answerid="7706">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="votecell">
              <div class="vote">
                <input type="hidden" name="_id_" value="7706">
                <a class="vote-up-off" title="Esta resposta é útil">votar a favor</a>
                <span class="vote-count-post ">3</span>
                <a class="vote-down-off" title="Esta resposta não é útil">votar contra</a>
              </div>
            </td>

            <td class="answercell">
              <div class="post-text">
                <p>Um arquivo HTML com extensão .php vai se comportar <strong>exatamente como HTML</strong>. O interpretador PHP só entra em cena para o que estiver entre <code>&lt;? ... ?&gt;</code>. </p>
                <p>Neste contexto o ideal é usar tudo .php.</p>
              </div>

              <table class="fw">
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>';
  }

}
```

Sim, acredite... tem programadores que fazem isso. Então **NUNCA** faça isso.

Comment: Porque é que é má prática fazer dessa forma?

Comment: @JorgeB. por "n" motivos, vou listar alguns: 1) difícil manutenção do código. 2) difícil indentação do código. 3) caractere de escape necessário as vezes. 4) faz com que seu código/classe se torne bem maior. 5) pequena perda de performance dependendo do tamanho e/ou operações dentro do código/html. Mas a principal questão é a legibilidade do código, sendo assim, é melhor manter isso em um arquivo externo e apenas injetar/chamar ele no momento da resposta.

Answer (score 6):

Quando você pergunta:

> se modifico todos os meus documentos para .php ou se utilizo o php
>   dentro do html

Na verdade não são opções mutuamente excludentes: para "utilizar o PHP dentro do HTML" você **precisa** modificar o documento para ".php"! :-)

Você pode, alternativamente, manter os arquivos HTML como estão, e fazer o PHP em separado.

Assim mesmo, em algum momento, você usaria o PHP para ler esse arquivo HTML e modificá-lo.

Em geral, os *frameworks* PHP solicitam alterações no arquivo HTML, seja usando uma linguagem de *template* específica (Blade, Twig, ou outra), ou utilizando o próprio PHP como linguagem de *template*, para integrar os dados obtidos no banco de dados com o *markup*.

---

Retomando a questão por outro ângulo...

> Utilizo Php dentro de um Html ou um Html dentro de um Php?

Você pode incrementar o seu *site* feito em HTML e CSS acrescentando primeiramente **JavaScript**.

O ideal seria fazer a comunicação entre o lado do cliente, onde habitam HTML, CSS e JS, totalmente com JS - inclusive viabilizando que esse mesmo *site* use qualquer linguagem no lado do servidor, sem ser modificado.

Você usaria uma biblioteca como jQuery ou AngularJS ou Breeze ou outra para solicitar os dados do servidor via Ajax, fazendo as requisições para ler, criar, atualizar ou remover dados do servidor (CRUD = Create, Retrieve, Update, Destroy = INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE...)

Desse jeito, você não mistura PHP com HTML. Ou seja, nem PHP dentro de HTML, e nem HTML dentro de PHP. Este seria o **ideal**.

O máximo que você puder fazer para evitar a mistura de PHP com HTML, faça.

---

Por outro lado, você pode enxergar o PHP como uma linguagem de *templates*.

Com um uso muito bem disciplinado, você pode aproveitar as estruturas de controle que a linguagem oferece para montar o seu HTML a partir do servidor incluindo variáveis:

```
<p>Seja bem vindo, <?php echo htmlentities($usuario); ?>.</p>
```

Essa utilização do PHP dentro do HTML, como uma linguagem de *template*, é aceitável, e existem *frameworks* que te ajudam muito a manter as coisas nos seus devidos lugares (sou fã do [Laravel 4](http://laravel.com)).

Outro exemplo:

```
<?php foreach ($itens as $item): ?>
<div>Item <?php echo htmlentities($item->nome); ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Isto é PHP dentro de HTML ou HTML dentro de PHP? Fica difícil dizer. No caso, ainda estamos usando o PHP como "linguagem de template".

O HTML dentro do PHP propriamente dito seria assim:

```
<?php
    foreach ($itens as $item) {
        echo '<div>Item ' . htmlentities($item->nome) . '</div>';
    }
?>
```

Esse tipo de coisa deve ser evitado.

Quando o teu código conecta o banco de dados, faz consultas, *updates*, verifica se o usuário mandou dados, valida formulários, e no meio disso tudo vai soltando uns HTMLs... isso é comum, mas é medonho - é o código "*espaguete*", que naturalmente vai se formando para iniciantes, mas deve ser evitado a todo custo.

> No fim das contas, **não há diferença** entre "PHP dentro de HTML" e
>   "HTML dentro de PHP".

Na prática, quando o arquivo contém a extensão ".php" fazendo com que, por padrão, ative o interpretador da linguagem PHP ao ser servido por um servidor HTTP (como o Apache ou o NginX), **ambos**, a marcação HTML e o código PHP (envolvido dentro de `<?php`e `?>`) serão processados. O HTML fica inalterado, enquanto que o que está dentro das tags mencionadas é executado (eventualmente repetindo o HTML, como vimos).

Answer (score 4):

Para ativar o php dentro do html, vc teria que configurar o seu servidor (Apache, IIS etc.) para processar arquivos html utilizando o PHP. Essa não é a configuração mais comum.

O normal mesmo é processar com o PHP apenas os arquivos com extensão .php

Comment: Entendi, mas no caso se eu transformar meus arquivos .html para .php, eles vão funcionar normalmente ?

Comment: Sim. O interpretador PHP só processa código dentro das tags `<?php ... ?>`, o resto é passado sem alteração. Normalmente arquivos HTML podem ser renomeados para .php sem nenhum efeito inesperado.

Comment: Verdade, Havenard. Porém você precisa lembrar também de alterar qualquer link que aponta para um endereço "blablabla.html" para "blablabla.php" // o seu programa editor deve ser capaz de fazer essa conversão dos links automaticamente para você.

Comment: Claro. Naturalmente os arquivos que os links apontam precisam existir. Alterar a extensão implica que o nome do arquivo foi alterado, e os links apontando pra ele precisam ser corrigidos.

Comment: Os links também podem ser mantidos como estão, configurando o apache para reescrever as urls.

Comment: Mas quando eu terminar meu site e for publicar, alguma dessas alterações, tanto modificar para .php, quanto configurar o apache, vai ter alguma influência no funcionamento ?

Comment: No caso do apache, você configura a reescrita de urls num arquivo htaccess na raiz do site. Esse arquivo precisa ser publicado junto com os outros.

Comment: Valeu gnt, brigado..

Answer (score 4):

O que for estático, mantenha estático.
Exemplo, uma página HTML na qual não há necessidade em usar banco de dados ou recursos do PHP, não há motivos para usar PHP.

Simples assim... a menos que tenha algum motivo muito específico para parsear um determinado conteúdo estático dentro do compilador do PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Eu imagino que não seja essa exatamente sua dúvida, mas o ideal é manter a mistura entre HTML e PHP ao mínimo. Isso facilita mudar as coisas dos dois lados, então sempre busque escrever um arquivo PHP com todas as funções necessárias - de preferência, que comece com `<?php` e nem feche a tag - que vai ser invocado por algumas partes do seu HTML.

Voltando à sua pergunta, a configuração mais comum é que o seu HTML inclua algumas tags PHP e tenha extensão .php. Você pode também fazer com que o HTML seja apenas um modelo, que é carregado pelo código PHP e modificado nas partes dinâmicas.