# É uma boa prática misturar Php e Html?

Tags: php, html, estilo-de-codificação

Vejo que em python, tem o bottle por exemplo que faz a mesma coisa do que eu pretendo fazer então...

Eu sou novo em práticas web, estudante de fato e gostaria de saber se posso utilizar php e html no mesmo lugar,queria saber se isso é um padrão, não recomendado, ou tanto faz. Só está Body porque eu pretendo usar Ajax e carregar os posts sem dar refresh na página.

Segue o código exemplo:

```
<?php
    function __autoload($class_name){
        require_once  $class_name . '.php';
    }
?>

<body>
<?php 
    $noticia = new Noticia();
?>
<div id="posts">
<?php foreach ($noticia->findAll() as $value): ?>
    <div style=" word-wrap: break-word; width: 400px; ">

    <?php echo $value->mensagem; ?> <br><br><br><br>

    </div> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Pergunta relacionada (possivelmente duplicata): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7703/utilizo-php-dentro-de-um-html-ou-um-html-dentro-de-um-php

Comment: Não tem nada ver com essa pergunta aí. Quero saber se atualmente os desenvolvedores php desenvolvem dessa forma, ou se tem outra forma. Essa pergunta não respondeu minha dúvida.

Comment: Ok Asura, por isso que eu disse "relacionada" e "possivelmente". Não sinalizei, nem votei pra fechar, foi apenas uma sugestão. Até já tinha dado +1 na sua pergunta, porque achei bem feita, em que pese ter pensado que ela poderia ser duplicata.

Comment: Em minha opinião, 'Não', muitos dos programadores que eu conheço também não preferem esta mistura. É preferível utilizar um Projeto MVC, que separa o conteúdo, na qual uma `view` recebem as variaves a serem utilizadas. Sugido estudar MVC, um bom exemplo é o 'cakePHP'

Comment: Não é recomendado. Procure por algum engine e template. Se tiver usando algum framework eles já indicam um padrão.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

É um padrão.

Não é recomendado.

Não é uma boa prática.

Em muitos casos tanto faz.

Existe um princípio no design de software chamado ***separation of concerns***, que determina que cada parte do sistema se preocupe com uma coisa apenas.

No seu caso, o princípio determinaria que uma parte separada do seu código deve cuidar da **apresentação**, outra parte deve cuidar da **estrutura** do que está sendo apresentado, outra parte deve cuidar do **conteúdo** apresentado, e você pode ter ainda partes distintas para cuidar da **lógica de apresentação** e da **lógica de negócio**.

Se você quiser seguir este princípio, você deveria ter arquivos html, arquivos css, arquivos php... cada um com uma responsabilidade ou uma "preocupação" diferente.

Este princípio é amplamente aceito e acredita-se que a sua não observação em aplicativos grandes ou complexos acarreta na dificuldade (aumento do custo) de manutenção e evolução do sistema e redução da qualidade do software.

Answer (score 11):

Dizer se é ou não uma boa prática depende muito de opinião.

Essa é uma prática utilizada, por exemplo, nos arquivos de template do Wordpress, que misturam HTML e PHP. Além disso, pelo padrão [PSR-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/pt-br/) proposto pelo *PHP Framework Interop Group* (vários frameworks já aderiram - Joomla, Laravel Yii, etc.):

> Arquivos DEVERIAM ou declarar símbolos (classes, funções, constantes, etc.) ou causar efeitos colaterais (e.g. gerar output, modificar configurações no php.ini, etc.), mas NÃO DEVERIAM fazer ambos.

Dessa maneira você deve se preocupar apenas em não definir funções/classes no arquivo do seu exemplo para respeitar o padrão.

Mais informações em http://www.php-fig.org/ (parcialmente traduzido)

---

Note que essa não é uma regra. Se o site que você está desenvolvendo é mais complexo do que apenas um blog é recomendado fazer uma separação utilizando MVC ou uma biblioteca de templates como sugerido nas outras resposta.

Comment: Não conhecia essa PSR. Agradeço por me mostra-la.

Answer (score 7):

Acho totalmente normal usar essas "práticas web", mas isso depende do jeito que o programador acha mais fácil desenvolver e fazer futuras manutenções. Ou você pode fazer um função para cada coisa que a aplicação faz (Que é mais fácil para fazer manutenções) :
main.php

```
class News { ...
 public function getAllNews() {
      foreach ($noticia->findAll() as $value) {
           echo $value->mensagem; ?>
      }
 }
```

}

index.php:

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name){
    require_once  $class_name . '.php';
}   $noticia = new Noticia(); ?>

<body>
<div id="posts">
<?php $noticia->getAllNews(); ?>
</body>
```

Uma pratica muito usada por programadores é o MVC: Na qual uma view recebem as variáveis a serem utilizadas, e as funções geralmente ficam na class Model separado da view.
http://www.tutsup.com/2014/09/17/mvc-em-php-parte-1/

Answer (score 7):

Não é recomendável misturar PHP com HTML, eu gosto muito, e até incentivo meus alunos, a usarem uma biblioteca chamada Smarty, com ele podemos gerenciar templates sem misturar php com HTML. Veja um exemplo:

NoticiaView.php

```
class NoticiaView {
/**
 * @all controllers must contain an index method
 */
function index(){

    $smarty = new \Smarty;

    $smarty->debugging = false;
    $smarty->caching = false;
    $smarty->cache_lifetime = 120;

    $nc = new NoticiaControl();

    $smarty->append("news",$nc->getNews(),true);

    $smarty->display('notica.tpl');
}

}
```

notica.tpl

```
<html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
          {foreach $news as $n}
               {$n->valorDaNoticia()}
          {/foreach}
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ao meu ver de estudante ignorante no assunto, parece uma mistura não-óbvia. É tipo o bottle.py .

Answer (score 6):

Isso pode e deve variar dependendo do `tipo de arquivo` que você está trabalhando. Se você seguir o `padrão MVC`, seu ponto de vista deve ser o último.
Tente manter uma `separação de exibição/formatação de saída e a lógica` que fornece os dados.

Exemplo:

```
<?php
  # aqui você define algumas funções aqui que fornecem dados
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php foreach ($noticia->findAll() as $value): ?>
  <p>
    <?=$value;?>
  </p>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Não é uma boa prática, isso `dificulta` muito `manutenções` futuras, o ideal seria o uso da arquitetura `MVC`, onde você separa seu `model, controller e view`. Para facilitar sua vida, tem um framework para views muito bom, que recomendo que é o `twig`, quando começar a programar em MVC não irá querer mudar mais.

Answer (score 4):

Isso não é uma boa prática misturar o `controller` (lógica do sistema) com a `view` (parte visual do programa que interfaceia com o usuário), para nos evadir dos problemas acarretados por esta mistura e ganharmos mais segurança operacional (o Web Designer e o Desenvolvedor podem trabalhar ao mesmo tempo sem que o trabalho de um interfira no outro) é usado `templates`

Exemplos de templates:

**Smarty:** [Link para download e documentação](http://www.smarty.net/)

**Dwoo:** [Link para download e documentação](http://dwoo.org/)

Exemplo de uso (na documentação é fornecido mais exemplos para outras funcionalidades):

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <blockquote>

    Knock knock! <br/>
    Who's there? <br/>
    {$name}      <br/>
    {$name} who? <br/>
    {$punchline}
    </blockquote>

  </body>
</html>

<?php
// auto-loader
include 'dwooAutoload.php';

// cria objeto Dwoo 
$dwoo = new Dwoo();

// le o templete acima definido
$tpl = new Dwoo_Template_File('tmpl/knock.tpl');

// valores dinamicos que serão injetados no template
$data = array();
$data['name'] = 'Boo';
$data['punchline'] = 'Don\'t cry, it\'s only a joke';

// injeta os valores e exibe a pagina, note que o nome do indices são identicos as 
//variaveis dentro do template, o dwoo irá fazer a injeção paseado nos nomes identicos.
$dwoo->output($tpl, $data);
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Quando você utiliza PHP junto com o HTML você de alguma forma estará misturando a regras de negócios com regras de apresentação. Você deve ver uma forma de manter isso separado, seja através de bibliotecas como Smarty ou Twig, ou de uma outra arquitetura além do MVC, como REST por exemplo, que possibilita uma separação muito maior do que a VIEW do MVC.

Misturando o PHP com o HTML vai funcionar da mesma maneira, e caso o projeto seja pequeno talvez nem convém ficar estudando várias tecnologias, mas a questão é sobre boas práticas e a arquitetura do código. Neste ponto é recomendável aumentar ainda mais seus conhecimentos a respeito disso para utilizar em projetos maiores.