# Por que não é aconselhável utilizar os códigos PHP no mesmo documento de HTML?

Tags: php, html, estilo-de-codificação

Eu estava no laboratório hoje mostrando um exemplo de código simples em PHP a um colega e o meu professor viu e perguntou "Por que você está colocando PHP junto com o HTML?". Mesmo sem entender muito respondi que era apenas um exemplo simples que eu tinha feito pra mostrar pro colega. Ele retrucou dizendo que mesmo sendo um exemplo não era aconselhável fazer isso. Eu deveria ter perguntado o porquê a ele, mas não perguntei e fiquei com essa pequena dúvida.

Por que não é aconselhável utilizar o PHP junto com o HTML? Devo criar um documento específico só pro PHP separado do HTML? Como faço pra chamar esses códigos em PHP sem ter que alterar o conteúdo da página?

Comment: Não é bem assim, talvez o melhor era mesmo você perguntar para ele, ou então postar como você fez o código ... mesmo assim pode ser resposta baseado em opinião própria, no final das contas não tem como muito fugir disso ... os framework tenta serparar ao máximo, como uma forma de organização ... mas, diz ai o que você mostrou para o amigo.

Comment: Você deve separar pois fica mais fácil a manutenção de código com cada tipo de código no "seu quadrado" ou no seu devido arquivo. No exemplo que você viu no laboratório, talvez não fizesse muito sentido separar, pois havia pouco código, mas quando você for pra um ambiente corporativo, haverá muito mais código e essa separação se faz necessária. Porem eu nunca vi essa separação ser 100%, eu mesmo uso bastando `foreach` em arquivo HTML, mas eu sempre tento usar em menor quantidade.

Comment: Só pelo fato de você se questionar isso, já começou certo. Parabéns.

Comment: Meu professor um dia me disse: "quem pergunta passa por leigo uma vez, quem não pergunta será sempre leigo!"

Comment: [É uma boa prática misturar Php e Html?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/62516/91) e [Utilizo PHP dentro de um HTML ou um HTML dentro de um PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7703/91) e um [exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16398/91) que mistura html com php e outro que separa.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

Eu sou dos seus, em coisas simples faça do jeito mais simples possível.

Claro que se está aprendendo o ideal é aprender fazer mesmo em exemplos simples do jeito que se faz quando o projeto é complexo, multidisciplinar, em equipe e exigirá muita manutenção. Sabendo fazer o complexo ajuda fazer o simples, desde que não perca de vista a forma simplificada. Uma pena que muitos programadores acabam adotando a complexa até nos casos que não precisa disso tudo. Então dou razão para o professor também, só acho que ele deveria ter explicado o porquê, professores servem para isso. Pode ser que ele deixou para você se virar, bons professores também fazem isso, mas não deixa você perdido o tempo todo.

A resposta está na pergunta. A separação ajuda cada arquivo ter sua responsabilidade, então uma cuida do visual da página e outra cuida do comportamento que ela terá. Isso ajuda testar, dar manutenção e até trocar por outro componente se for bem-feito e dar margem para o intercâmbio de partes.

Não quer dizer que o HTML não possa ter nada de PHP, pode o necessário para montar a página, tem que ser bem simples, mas não para manipular dados, fazer processamento real, cuidar das regras de negócio.

Entenda o todo para tomar suas próprias decisões.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

Complementando as respostas, vale lembrar que arquivos HTML não suportam arquivos PHP, pôs arquivos PHP são server side e arquivos HTML são Client side. Talvez seja isso que seu professor queria falar.

Link: [DIFERENÇA ENTRE SERVER-SIDE E CLIENT-SIDE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/608/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-c%C3%B3digo-client-side-e-server-side-em-desenvolvimento-web)

---

Uma observação, arquivos PHP podem ser totalmente montados sem haver nenhum código PHP dentro do mesmo, somente com HTML puro, o que muda, é que a qualquer momento, posso colocar código PHP no mesmo. Ja arquivos HTML, não podem conter nada de PHP, pôs não vai ser executado, o arquivo .html não entende aquele código em PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo,mais cedo ou mais tarde você vai ter que integrar as duas linguagens,a menos que você não queira uma página dinamica! porém,é aconselhavel reduzir o maximo possivel a "mistura" das das linguagens,na verdade você vai separar as responsabilidades ! como assim ? exemplo: voce quer salvar uma informação em um banco de dados.vai precisar fazer  conexao com ele,obviamente! vc pode simplesmente jogar o codigo php no meio do codigo em html,mas isso NÂO é uma boa pratica! o ideal é vc criar um novo arquivo na msm pasta (ex: conexao_banco.php), e ali dentro voce coloca todas as funçoes e variaveis relacionadas a conexão,ai no html vc faz apenas um 'include "conexao_banco.php" ' . desse modo é como se voce tivesse posto o codigo ali,mas n vai ver ,assim fica mais facil de voce trabalhar em cima do html,e seu codigo fica mais organizado! entendeu ?

Answer (score 0):

Correto. Arquivos PHP, valem salientar, exige muito do servidor. O ideal é construir seu projeto todo em html, ajax e jquery, fazendo requisição ao PHP que está localizado externamente, em outra pasta. Dessa forma, a exigência ao servidor reduzirá drasticamente. Esse é o verdadeiro motivo para não incluir o PHP diretamente na página HTML. Espero ter ajudado.