# Como chamar um método PHP no HTML ao dar submit em um formulario?

Tags: php, html, webforms

Eu tenho um formulário onde eu insiro alguns dados,quando eu der submit, eu quero passar esses dados, como parâmetro de um método e ja fazer a execução do mesmo. Alguém consegue me explicar como fazer?

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7703/utilizo-php-dentro-de-um-html-ou-um-html-dentro-de-um-php

Comment: Vlw mesmo cara, deu uma clareada aqui de como fazer!