# Como inserir um arquivo HTML dentro de uma variável PHP?

Tags: php, html, phpmailer, dompdf

Fala galera,

Tenho um arquivo chamado `post_forms.php`que pega os resultados do `$_POST[]`, deve preencher variáveis dentro do arquivo `form_xxx.html`, criar um PDF com a lib DomPDF e enviar com PHPMAiler.
Vejam uma parte de cada arquivo:

**post_forms.php**

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR", "pt_BR.iso-8859-1", "pt_BR.utf-8", "portuguese"); 
date_default_timezone_set('America/Bahia');
$data_cadastro = utf8_encode(ucfirst(strftime('%A, %d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S')));
$tipo_form = $_POST['tipo-form'];
$protocolo = 'DA'.date("Ymdis");

switch ($tipo_form)
{
    case"Form A":
    ob_start();
    include("forms/form_A.html");;
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    break;
}

echo $html;

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
```

**form_A.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <table class="table table-bordered" style="text-align:center;">
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2" align="center"><img src="img/logo.png"></th>
                <th colspan="4" style="font-size: 1.5em;">FORMULÁRIO - Formulário Tipo A</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2"><strong>$tipo_form</strong> - <big>$protocolo</big></th>
                <th colspan="2"> $data_cadastro</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                ...
            </tr>
            <tr>
                ...
            </tr>
            <tr>
                ...
            </tr>
            <tr>
                ...
            </tr>
        </table>
    </main>

    <script> ... </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Não tenho problema nenhum com as classes DomPDF e nem com PHPMailer, consigo gerar o pdf e enviar por email.
O que preciso saber é, por que as variáveis PHP que estão dentro do arquivo html, estão sendo escritas com a String contendo o nome da variável Ex: `$data_cadastro` e não está sendo impresso o conteudo da variável que seria por Ex: **Sábado, 08/09/2018,
11:34:00**

Comment: Amigo tenta o seguinte.... mudar  a linha  <th colspan="2"><strong>$tipo_form</strong> - <big>$protocolo</big></th>
                <th colspan="2"><? echo $data_cadastro?> </th> para   <th colspan="2"><strong>$tipo_form</strong> - <big><?=$protocolo?></big></th>
                <th colspan="2"><?echo $data_cadastro?></th>

Comment: Veja a resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7703/utilizo-php-dentro-de-um-html-ou-um-html-dentro-de-um-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Encontrei o problema, faltava as tags `<?php ?>` e a chamada do echo
>   no arquivo **.html**

**form_A.html**

```
                <th colspan="2"> <?php echo $data_cadastro; ?></th>
```